# Ajax.Updater to execute js

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have tried many online tutorials and examples nothing much paid off..

I need to run the js from HTML Response in Ajax.

My Code:

```
<script src="prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
function showmsg()
{
new Ajax.Updater('main', 'getmsg.php?q=1', { method: 'get' },{evalScripts:true}); 
}
</script>
```

getmsg.php contains: (testing purpose)

```
$q=$_GET[q];
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");

if ($q==1)
echo 'hi
<script type="text/javascript">
 type = function(){
    var a =2;   
    if(a>1)
    alert(\'random number 87\');
    }
type();
</script>';
```

I need to run this type() function in main page after ajax call. But the output is just 'hi'

PS: if this script works, will it work on all browsers?

Can someone please help me out..

Answer (score 1):

I think you just missbuilt your parameters array, try this :

```
new Ajax.Updater('main', 'getmsg.php?q=1', { method: 'get', evalScripts:true});
```